# Silent initdb.exe postgresql

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, cmd, runas

I am trying to install postgresql on a server using a bat file. I am using initdb.exe with --pwfile option so that it picks up the password form a text file and continues...

for some reason, even with --pwfile option, it is still prompting me for a password.. Not sure what the problem is.. This is the script I am using:

```
set DBPATH = something 
set DBADMIN = something 

set DBDATA = something

RunAs /noprofile /user:%computername%\postgres ""%DBPATH%\initdb.exe" --locale=C --encoding=UTF-8 -U %DBADMIN% --pwfile="D:\Pass.txt" -D "%DBDATA%""
```

Thanks

Comment: My guess is, the password prompt comes from the `runas` command,  not from `initdb`. There is no way to suppress the password prompt from `runas`. But why are you using `runas` at all? Postgres does not require a special (Windows) user account any more (you just need to get permissions right on the data directory)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a software which requires for the installation administrator privileges and the current user account does not have the required privileges, it is possible to use command [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) to run the installation executable and all processes started by this application with a different user account than the current user account which has the required privileges.

But the user has to enter nevertheless a password - the password for the other user account with the extended privileges to install applications. If it would be possible to run something requiring extended privileges for installing software without requesting entering the password by the user, every bad guy out in the world could very easily install trojaners and other malware (as it is possible on Windows 2000 / XP or since Windows Vista with user account control disabled).

There are systems to deploy and install software on all clients of a company like [Group Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) or [System Center Configuration Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager).